# Notation for "the equation of the line $ \overleftrightarrow{AB} $ is $ y=mx+c $"

Tags: geometry, notation

Does there exist some widely accepted notation that is equivalent to the following sentence?

> The equation of the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is $y=mx+c$

I'd like to express this without the use of words.

Comment: I typically write something like $$\overleftrightarrow{AB}:\; y = mx + c$$

Comment: @Blue Does $\overrightarrow{AB}$ mean something different to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ ?

Comment: *segment*: $\overline {AB}$. *ray*: $\overrightarrow {AB}$. *line*: $\overleftrightarrow {AB}$.

Comment: Interesting. So in my situation, I actually want to use $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In what disciplines are the latter two notations used as popular/standard notations? I've never seen the symbol $\overleftrightarrow {AB}$ before. And in mathematics, $\overrightarrow{AB}$ more often than not denotes a vector rather than the ray (half line) in that direction.

Comment: @user1551 - Geometry. See Edwin Moise, [Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint](https://books.google.it/books?id=3UjvAAAAMAAJ). Addison-Wesley (3rd ed 1990), page 65.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the notations

$$
\overleftrightarrow{AB}: \,\, y=mx+c
$$

or

$$
r_{AB}: \,\, y=mx+c
$$